Why is my number of rows getting reduced when applying Standard Scaler?
I'm applying StandardScaler() to standardize my dataset. But the resultant standardized dataset has fewer rows than the original dataset. Why is this happening? I want to retain the original number of rows after standardization.
After applying the StandardScaler() function, I expected to get the same number of rows with the standardized values.

Always show the code that you try

Although it shouldn't but still check for any transformation you might have done .
